# Fixtures for functional test is big and spent a lot of time to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to test a report-like rails view using rspec, the view shows a lot of data, and the fixures yaml for the view is almost 2M big and it cost a lot of time to load the fixtures.

Is there any way to solve this problem, and what should I do if I only want to load the fixtures once for all test.

Comment: That's not enough information to really say. It depends on what the view needs to do and what the specs need to demonstrate about that. Generally, you would want a long running integration test like this to only need to be run once in a great while (perhaps on a C.I. server after developers commit changes), and you would have a number of other much faster tests that together give you high confidence that the whole thing is working.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up test execution in general, and I'm sure loading of fixtures can be included, take a look at [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/).